# How to put just distinct values into select control MVC ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my index view. I tried with ViewBag but it doesn't work, maybe because I want to get values from foreign key. I am new to ASP.NET.

```
<form id="forma" action="/InspekcijskeKontrole/VratiKontrole" method="get">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Select1">Odaberite inspekcijsko tijelo:</label>
    <select name="Select1" id="Select1" class="form-control" onchange="sacuvaj()">
        <option value="-1">Selektujte inspekcijsko tijelo:</option>
        @foreach (var i in ViewBag.Select1) {
            <option value="@i.Value">@i.Text</option>
        }
    </select><br />
    <label for="Select2">Odaberite vremenski period kontrole:</label>
    <select name="Select2" id="Select2" class="form-control" onchange="sacuvaj1()">
        <option value="-1">Selektujte vremenski period kontrole:</option>
        @foreach(var i in Model)
        {
            <option value="@i.DatumInspekcijskeKontrole.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")">@i.DatumInspekcijskeKontrole.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

This is my controller

```
    public ActionResult VratiKontrole(int Select1, string Select2)
    {

        IEnumerable<string> tijelaNaziv = db.InspekcijskaKontrolas.OrderBy(i => i.InspekcijskoTijelo.NazivInspekcijskogTijela).Select(i => i.InspekcijskoTijelo.NazivInspekcijskogTijela).Distinct();
        ViewBag.Select1 = new SelectList(tijelaNaziv);


        IQueryable<InspekcijskaKontrola> listaKontrola = db.InspekcijskaKontrolas.Select(i => i);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Select1.ToString())&&!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Select2.ToString()))
        {
            string[] parts = Select2.Split('.');
            DateTime datum = new DateTime(int.Parse(parts[2]), int.Parse(parts[1]), int.Parse(parts[0]));
            listaKontrola = listaKontrola.Where(l => l.InspekcijskoTijeloId == Select1).Where(l => l.DatumInspekcijskeKontrole == datum).Select(l => l);
        }

        return View(listaKontrola.ToList());

    }
```

Comment: You are calling `Distinct()` . Is that not giving you the distinct values ? What is your real problem ? Is there a specific reason you are not using Html.DropDownListFor helper method ?

Comment: No I just got error null reference maybe because this is foreign key ?

Comment: Which line you got null reference ? Please include the relevant details in the question itself.

Comment: On `@foreach (var i in ViewBag.Select1) {
            <option value="@i.Value">@i.Text</option>
        }` ViewBag.Select1

Comment: I don't use helper because I want to do filtration with this select control

Comment: How to do it with helper I didn't try maybe it is easier ?

Comment: Could be a problem because I change my controller with ViewBag after I create view It should be ?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

This is solved. I just put into view:

```
@foreach (var i in Model.Select(i=>i.InspekcijskoTijelo).Distinct()) {
    <option value="@i.InspekcijskoTijeloId">@i.NazivInspekcijskogTijela</option>
}
```